# Using textfile for user input and save with button android studio

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager, user-input

Okay, I have a viewpager/slider that for each different page it has some type of information on it. The one I am having problems with is the Message tab. This tab is suppose to let the user input a message and then save it with the button that is pushed. (this information will be later used to send in an text message) But when the button is pushed it crashes and then loops back into the program, starting it over again.

I don't know if this is right but at first I put that button method in the main activity.java and it did not work at all. Then I made a new activity to hold that method and it worked up until the button was clicked. Below is the code and the log.

message activity

```
package akh.senpro;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainMenu_Message extends Fragment {

View rootView;
int count = 0;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_menu__message, container, false);
    //TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
    //text.setText("Message");


    return rootView;
}




}
```

message xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="     "
    android:id="@+id/text_message"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Enter your emergency message below"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#A4C639" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#0099FF"
    android:text="save"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the new activity that holds the button

```
package akh.senpro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FrmActivityMessage extends Activity {

Button mButton;
EditText mEdit;
TextView mText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu__message);
}

public void buttonClicked(View v){
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mText.setText("Thank you "+mEdit.getText().toString()+"!");
        }
    });
}
}
```

new activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainMenu_Message"
android:onClick="buttonClicked"
android:clickable="true">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/Save"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="185dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the log

```
04-13 18:07:25.574    2812-2827/akh.senpro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use     EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-13 18:07:25.582    2812-2812/akh.senpro D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host     Connection established 0xb3eb3e80, tid 2812
04-13 18:07:25.641    2812-2812/akh.senpro D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-13 18:07:25.939    2812-2824/akh.senpro I/art﹕ Background sticky     concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4494(296KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS     objects, 34% free, 731KB/1117KB, paused 2.485ms total 166.251ms
04-13 18:07:25.981    2812-2827/akh.senpro D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host     Connection established 0xb3eb3590, tid 2827
04-13 18:07:26.039    2812-2827/akh.senpro I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL,     version 1.4
04-13 18:07:26.172    2812-2827/akh.senpro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-13 18:07:26.223    2812-2827/akh.senpro W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-13 18:07:26.223    2812-2827/akh.senpro W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set     EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f9b320, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-13 18:07:26.522    2812-2812/akh.senpro I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-13 18:07:29.519    2812-2827/akh.senpro W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-13 18:07:29.519    2812-2827/akh.senpro W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5112180, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-13 18:07:56.778    2812-2812/akh.senpro D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-13 18:07:56.779    2812-2812/akh.senpro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: akh.senpro, PID: 2812
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method buttonClicked(View) in the activity class akh.senpro.MainActivity2Activity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: buttonClicked [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-13 18:21:44.539    3005-3005/akh.senpro I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3005 SIG: 9
04-13 18:21:44.945    3030-3045/akh.senpro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use     EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-13 18:21:44.950    3030-3030/akh.senpro D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3eb3ed0, tid 3030
04-13 18:21:44.956    3030-3030/akh.senpro D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-13 18:21:45.046    3030-3045/akh.senpro D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3eb36e0, tid 3045
04-13 18:21:45.074    3030-3045/akh.senpro I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-13 18:21:45.121    3030-3045/akh.senpro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-13 18:21:45.154    3030-3045/akh.senpro W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-13 18:21:45.154    3030-3045/akh.senpro W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3fda3e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: no I changed the whole idea.

Comment: so are you 100% okay with the whole idea logic, if maybe you have any problems maybe i might be of help

Comment: the logic of your answer looks fine. I will try it out a little later though because I changed the idea completely since I couldn't get it to work at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIrst all Sir, your Error is this `NoSuchMethodException` the specified method could not be found in your activity class `MainActivity2Activity`.

you have to know that `mButton.setOnClickListener()` is the same as `public void buttonClicked(View v)` so you do not need to do

```
public void buttonClicked(View v){
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mText.setText("Thank you "+mEdit.getText().toString()+"!");
    }
});
}
```

also if you have `Activty A` that has `xml A` is its View `content` then everything declared in `xml A` is handled by `Activity A` so your app is crashing because you have declared `android:onClick="buttonClicked"` in your xml that is probably being handled by `MainActivity2Activity` and that activity has no method declared as such. if you want your `Fragment` class to handle the `onclick` then go the traditional way `mButton.setOnClickListener(//new onclick listener);` and put the codes there

second of all please initialise your variables in `onStart()` or `onCreate()` instead of initialising them when you click the button.

hope am lucid enough for you

Comment: eh, I follow a little bit. I am new to this. I will look up how to have the fragment class handle it.